# How to draw non square Go board in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, pstricks

As the title says, the square Go board is easy to draw with lots of Go board packages, such as `igo` or `psgo`.
But there is no way to draw a non square Go board support.
How do I draw rectangular Go boards?

I have found a paper that draw these Go boards, but don't know how it was done...

The paper is:

> van der Werf, Erik CD, and Mark HM Winands. "Solving Go for
>   rectangular boards." Icga Journal 32.2 (2009): 77-88.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.Se](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing what you've tried

Comment: the `igo` package is not currently in my LaTeX distrubution, but As far as I can tell, you wan't to redefine the places where the *goban* is defined. I think you wan't to change the command `\gobansize{n}` to `\gobansize{n}{m}` To draw a rectangular board.

Comment: looking at the source I see that `igo` is plain TeX, I have no idea how to create an optional argument to have non-square go boards.

Comment: I think the best way is to use `psgo` as it seems like it has the ability to draw the boards you wan't just not a way of doing it for the end user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really easy to do using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). Here is a really quick mock-up of a macro `\GoBoard` for drawing beads on a go board to produce:

[image]

The syntax for the macro is:

```
 \GoBoard[x-dim][y-dim]{list of white pieces}{list of black pieces}
```

where the lists of white and black pieces are comma separated lists of coordinates. The y-dimension of the board is optional, defaulting to the x-dimension. The image above was drawn using

```
\GoBoard{7}[6]{(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4),(4,3),(5,3),(5,2),(5,1)}
           {(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,4),(6,4),(6,3),(6,2),(6,1)}
```

There is almost no styling in the code below, but it would be easy to add this, for example, by consulting the comprehensive [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual.

Here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

% \GoBoard[x-dim][y-dim]{list of white pieces}{list of black pieces}
\NewDocumentCommand\GoBoard{ m O{#1} m m}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
        white/.style={ball color=white},% add styling to suit your tastes
        black/.style={ball color=black}
     ]
     % first draw the grid
     \foreach \x in {0,...,#1} {
       \draw[thick](\x,0)--++(0,#2);
     }
     \foreach \y in {0,...,#2} {
       \draw[thick](0,\y)--++(#1,0);
     }
     % now draw the white pieces
     \foreach \wh in {#3} {
       \shade[white] \wh circle (5mm);
     }
     % now draw the black pieces
     \foreach \bl in {#4} {
       \shade[black] \bl circle (5mm);
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\GoBoard{7}[6]{(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4),(4,3),(5,3),(5,2),(5,1)}
           {(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,4),(6,4),(6,3),(6,2),(6,1)}

\end{document}
```