# Changing the fontsize while using the igo-package

Tags: fontsize, igo

Using the `igo-package` I am not able to change the fontsize with the normal `fontsize=12pt` command. The only way to get another size I have to add e.g. `\large` at the begin of the document. The reasons seems to be the redefinition of `\normalsize` in the `igo.sty` file (see line 458 and below). This is not a great issue but I am interested if there is a way to get the normal `fontsize=12pt` command working (without changing much the working system). By the way: the `psgo` package is not a solution for this issue.

Below my sample:

```
\documentclass[%
    ,fontsize   = 12pt %% not working
    ,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{igo}
\usepackage{lipsum,ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\RaggedRight
\large %% adding this gives cmr12.pfb without cmr10.pfb , e.g.
%% /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb
\lipsum[1]
%% --
\begin{minipage}[c][1.0\height][r]{0.5\textwidth}
\medskip
\normalgoban\gobansize{9}\cleargoban
\black{g7,c7,g3,c3}
\white[1]{g5,e7,c5,e3,b7,b8,b6,b4}
\shortstack{\showgoban\\Handicap-GO}
\medskip
\end{minipage}
%% --
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: igo.sty isn't in texlive  can you give a link?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is on ctan (and in miktex) https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/igo.

Comment: you can use `\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}` after loading igo, but then the size of the board will no longer adapt to size commands like \large or \small.

Comment: Since `igo.sty` is not in texlive, then you might want to consider [psgo](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pstricks/contrib/psgo/psgomanual.pdf) or a [tikz based solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424766)

Comment: @Luis, as I mentioned: psgo is not the right alternative. But I will look at the tiki based solutions.

Comment: @Luis, I locked at the mentioned tikz solution. But this means to rewrite the igo based package from scratch. Since the solution by Ulrike is not working, I will use the solution I got.

Comment: @Ulrich sorry if the possibilities I mentioned didn’t work for you. I hope that what Ulrike said in a previous comment  works well for you

Comment: I commented out the lines after 458 (the whole set) and then the font size command is working. Funny, but I have still to understand what happens.